# Saving DbContext do not save data to database

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

There is automatically created database for authorize users. I update my database my local tables. There are some tables like Klient, Ulica, Address. Models who describe this tables:

```
public partial class Klient
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Klient()
    {
        this.Abonements = new HashSet<Abonement>();
    }

    public int ID_klient { get; set; }
    public string FIO_klient { get; set; }
    public string Telephon { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ID_adress { get; set; }
    public string ID_Login { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Abonement> Abonements { get; set; }
    public virtual Adress Adress { get; set; }
}
public partial class Ulica
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Ulica()
    {
        this.Adresses = new HashSet<Adress>();
    }

    public int ID_ulica { get; set; }
    public string Nazvanie_ulicu { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
}
public partial class Adress
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Adress()
    {
        this.Klients = new HashSet<Klient>();
        this.Sotrudniks = new HashSet<Sotrudnik>();
    }

    public int ID_adress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Nomer_doma { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Nomer_kvartiru { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ID_ulica { get; set; }

    public virtual Ulica Ulica { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Klient> Klients { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Sotrudnik> Sotrudniks { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext of this model is :

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Klient> Klients { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Ulica> Ulicas { get; set; }
    // and others models of my database
}
```

When I try change standart AccountController and add some data to model Klient on Register method, I add this code to Register method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
              // some code
              var ulica = new Ulica() { Nazvanie_ulicu = model.Ulica };
                FitnesManager.Ulicas.Add(ulica);
                var adress = new Adress { Ulica = ulica, ID_ulica = ulica.ID_ulica, Nomer_doma = model.Nomer_doma, Nomer_kvartiru = model.Nomer_kvartiru};
                FitnesManager.Adresses.Add(adress);
                var klient = new Klient { FIO_klient = model.FIO, Telephon = model.Telephon, Adress = adress, ID_adress = adress.ID_adress, ID_Login = user.Id };
                var res = FitnesManager.Klients.Add(klient);
                await FitnesManager.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        // Появление этого сообщения означает наличие ошибки; повторное отображение формы
        return View(model);
    }
```

FitnesManager is DbContext value of AccountController

```
public Entities FitnesManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _fitnesManager ?? new Entities();
        }
        private set
        {
            _fitnesManager = value;
        }
    }
```

But when I call Register method any data do not add to database. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
return _fitnesManager ?? new Entities();
```

You are returning a new instance every time.  I think you were going for this style:

```
return _fitnesManager ?? (_fitnesManager = new Entities());
```

Either that, or just do this:

```
if (_fitnesManager == null)
   _fitnesManager = new Entities();
return _fitnesManager;
```